# ¿Cómo usar el plugin de jQuery dataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy intentando hacer un grid en MVC 5 con la ayuda del plugin jQuery dataTable, lo instale desde consola con `PM> Install-Package datatables.net` y puse las referencias en la vista de la siguiente manera

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.11/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Luego hice una tabla pequeña para probarlo pero el script del dataTable no parece funcionar ya que me muestra una tabla normal de html.

Aquí esta el código completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Zona</title>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.11/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.11/extensions/Responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Numero Zona</th>
                    <th>Nombre Zona</th>
                    <th>Perimetro</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Zona 1</td>
                <td>Perimetro 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Zona 2</td>
                <td>Perimetro 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grid').DataTable();
    });
  </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `dataTables` tiene una serie de configuraciones para la manipulación de datos del lado del cliente. La cantidad de opciones son demasiado extensas para para poder responderlas aquí. La forma mas simple de usarlo es con `$('#example').DataTable();`. Creo que lo más simple es ver si la consola te da algún error y editar la pregunta con el error.

Comment: la consola no me da ningún error, así que creo que estoy mal con las referencias, pero hasta ahora los ejemplos que he visto no me han ayudado

Answer (score 6):

Implemente la siguiente prueba y funciona correctamente

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grid').DataTable();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Zona</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Numero Zona</th>
                    <th>Nombre Zona</th>
                    <th>Perimetro</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Zona 1</td>
                <td>Perimetro 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Zona 2</td>
                <td>Perimetro 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Valida desde el Developer Tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, en la solapa `Network` si las librerias .js se estan resolviendo correctamente.

Comment: Lo intente así con sus referencias y sigue mostrandome la tabla normal de html

Comment: validaste lo que comente del Developer Tools ?

Comment: Sí, me marco error en esta linea `$('#grid').DataTable();` dice que DataTable no es una función

Comment: si marca ese problema en javascript quiere decir que el .js del DataTable no se esta cargando. O quizas el codigo donde asignas el $('#grid').DataTable(); se ejecuta antes de la linea donde defines el .js de las librerias

Comment: @Leandro tengo un problema Similar con Bootstrap version 3.3.5  ,  Este es el orden de mis link :                                                          `<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
`<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
`<link herf="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> `

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al ejemplo de Leandro y al codigo que muestras las referencias tanto a css como js no son las mismas.

Intenta utilizar solamente jquery.dataTables.css y jquery.dataTables.js, ya que quizá al cargar el archivo dataTables.bootstrap.min.js se este generando un conflicto interno de javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione, se debe poner la librería .js debajo del script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grid').DataTable();
    });
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```